# How to delete all lines between the pattern lines

Tags: linux, sed, awk, tcsh

I have text with either the following structure

```
bla bla more bla bla
$ 
PART  /  4402000LLINK    4401001
NAME ADHESIVE   8.0 mm LLINK Property                                           


        8.                  8.         2
END_PART
$
some other bla bla
```

But the line containing PART could be also:

```
PART  /  4402000   LLINK 4401001
```

or:

```
PART  /  4402000  LLINK  4401001
```

So strictly speaking the LLINK could occupy the columns from 16 to 23. 
Now I would like to delete all lines between the pattern lines. First pattern is line containing both PART and this LLINK. The second pattern is line containing END_PART. So at the end I will have this:

```
bla bla more bla bla 
$
$
some other bla bla
```

I am using CentOS with:

```
> echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
```

so, I can use sed or awk in tcsh e.g. Could you help. Thank you

Comment: Please, in the future, provide a more generic input example that is easier on the eyes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `sed` command can be used.

```
sed -i -r '/PART.*LLINK/,/END_PART/d' file
```

Comment: simple and efficient +1

Comment: unfortunately it is not working in my case - all the lines are deleted.

Comment: Hi @clement89. Could you please prove the code. Thank you

Comment: I tested it in my system before adding it here.

Comment: Hi @clement89. I used a variant of your solution: 
sed '/^PART.*LLINK/,/END_PART/d' which is working for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With awk, this seems to work :

```
$ cat file

bla  PART bla more bla bla
$ 
PART  /  4402000LLINK    4401001
NAME ADHESIVE   8.0 mm LLINK Property                                           
PART

        8.                  8.         2
END_PART
$
some other bla bla
AAAAA
PART  /  4402120   LLINK    4401001
NAME ADHESIVE   8.0 mm LLINK Property
PART
AAAAAAAAAA
        8.                  8.         2
END_PART
$AAAA
AAAAAsome other bla bla

awk '{if (($0!~/PART/ || $0!~/LLINK/) && stop == 0) {print} else {if ($0~/END_PART/) {stop=0} else {stop=1}}}' file

bla  PART bla more bla bla
$ 
$
some other bla bla
AAAAA
$AAAA
AAAAAsome other bla bla
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi @jeanrjc. I don't see in your awk code any mention of the LLINK. Could you please check. As I said I need to delete all the lines between the patterns. First pattern is line containing both PART and LLINK. Second pattern is END_PART. Thank you

Comment: @Drago : Sorry I forgot the LLINK part, it is fixed now. I modify the file sample, to make things clear. I hope this is what you expect, tell me otherwise.

Comment: Hi @jeanrjc. Unfortunately it is still not working in my CentOS environment. When I apply the code nothing is changed. Could  the tcsh be responsible for it? Thank you for your time